# Trying to read two .pkl files, both give differnt errors

Tags: python

I have two .pkl files I'm trying to read as plain text. I don't know how the files are structured as they're from a game dump from a program I didn't make (I don't know why the program doesn't translate these .pkl files). This is the code I'm using:

```
import pickle
import pprint

obj = pickle.load(open("encounter_fixed_paldea.pkl", "rb"))

with open("out.txt", "a") as f:
    pprint.pprint(obj, stream=f)
```

where 'encounter_fixed_paldea.pkl' is one of the files I'm trying to read. For this file I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haily\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    obj = pickle.load(open("encounter_fixed_paldea.pkl", "rb"))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x19'.
```

for the other file I get a different error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\haily\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\test.py", line 4, in <module>
    obj = pickle.load(open("encounter_wild_paldea.pkl", "rb"))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_pickle.UnpicklingError: unpickling stack underflow
```

encounter_wild_paldea.pkl is 90KB and encounter_fixed_paldea.pkl is 9KB if that makes a difference.

Comment: Pickles are not portable between Python versions; you have to know which version it was saved from, and use the same version to unpickle.

Comment: Are either of the files corrupted or truncated? Some googling suggests that `unpickling stack underflow` can be caused by a truncated pickle file.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what version of Python the program used, and I have no idea if the files might be corrupted. everything else the program gave me was fine so I don't think these files are corrupted?